# What is the significance/meaning of Apoc's name?

Tags: the-matrix, names

One of the crew members of the hovership *Nebuchadnezzar* is named "Apoc". What is the meaning/significance of that name? Is it short for something, or perhaps an acronym? A [recent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/250789/31936) suggests that it is short for "Apocalypse". [Another website](http://www.geocities.ws/evrenguven/symbol.htm) suggests that it might reference either "apocalypse", "apocrypha", or "apocryphal".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While researching this question I found an [old script of *The Matrix*](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Matrix,-The.html) in which Neo mentions that Apoc wrote a "Four Horsemen" virus. The script does not mention anything else about this virus, but the name of the virus combined with Apoc's name means that both are almost certainly a reference to the Biblical [Book of Revelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation) ([also called the Apocalypse or the Apocalypse of John](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01594b.htm)) since the Book of Revelation includes the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse. Therefore "Apoc" is short for "Apocalypse" rather than "apocrypha" or something similar.